# Deleting "." from a string by replacing it by "" in a pandas df column (series)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I'm using Python 3.11 / Pandas 2.1.2:
I was trying to use the replace method in order to remove all "." from a string in a dataframe-column/series.

Referencing the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html

I was using this statement to get the job done:
df['Columnname'].replace('.', '', regex=True, inplace=True)

Processing this, Python will delete the complete string. It would simply replace all characters in the string by "". The "dot" is/seems to be recognized as a wildcard in this context.
Setting "regex" to "False" would run without error but doesn't have have any effect on the string - doesn't delete/replace the ".". It would simply do nothing whatsoever.

What can be done to get this working?